# Javascript/jQuery UI plugin best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a HTML page which uses jQuery UI for Portlets/Resizable

My question is what is the best practice to write the JS code ?

1. I use the script reference as in my HTML

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js "></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
> ```

Is that a better approach OR should I include the 2 JS within my own JS folder and reference them ?

2 . Where do I write the jQuery UI coniguration code for Portlets/Resizable? Is it better to write this code within the HTML file itself OR should I write this in a separate JS file (say jquery-ui-config.js)
 I have the following code

```
$(function() {
$( ".column" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".column"
});
$( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
.find( ".portlet-header" )
.addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
.prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
.end()
.find( ".portlet-content" );
$( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
$( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
});


 var maxBorderCellWidth = 350;
    var minBorderCellWidth = 200;
    var resizeCenter = function () {
        var clientWidth  = $(window).innerWidth();
        var leftWidth = $( ".left" ).outerWidth(true);
        var rightWidth = $( ".right" ).outerWidth(true);
       $('.center').width(clientWidth-leftWidth-rightWidth);
    }

    $( ".left" ).resizable({
      maxWidth: maxBorderCellWidth,
      minWidth: minBorderCellWidth,
      handles: 'e',
      resize: function (event, ui){
          resizeCenter();
      }
    });
    $( ".right" ).resizable({
      maxWidth: maxBorderCellWidth,
      minWidth: minBorderCellWidth,
      handles: 'w',
      resize: function (event, ui){
          resizeCenter();  
      }
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your way is the practice standard. Just ues Google to CDN your jQuery file, it can speed up your site. Your know, Google has servers around this world.
2. I think it should put your js code into a separate file. Because most of your code's selector is handle HTML class element. Generally, class elements is use generally, so perhaps this code will perform not only a HTML page. So put it separately then you can modify them easily.